# Error Android en API 19

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

tengo un error en Android Studio con una APP que no se a que se refiere. Les comento que si la ejecuto en un dispositivo con Android 6.0.1. API 23 se ejecuta bien, pero en un dispositivo Android 4.4.2. API 19 me tira error.

Les adjunto los código del gradle y el error

GRADLE

```
dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.desarrollostello.gesis.gesise"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
```

Error en un dispositivo API 19

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/http/MessageConstraintException;
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 36.115 secs
Information:3 errors
```

GRACIAS !!!

Comment: Eso parece a error de compatibilidad con las dependencias, te recomiendo revisar a detalle los requisitos para las versiones de las dependencias que estás utilizando.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una dependencia duplicada `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime` con diferentes versiones. Deberás dejar alguna de las dos, porque al tener las dos, te genera conflictos.

De estos dos, elimina alguno:

```
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }

compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
```

Comment: Gracias cnbandicoot comente el httpcore y funciona en API19 pero no se porque no funciona el botón de login. Si funciona en API23 pero en el Android 4.4.2. lo presiono pero no hace nada ni tira error ni nada.

Comment: El codigo del boton es el siguiente
`
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEntrar"

            android:text="@string/ingresar"

            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

            android:textSize="25sp"

            android:layout_width="270dp"

            android:layout_height="60dp"

            android:background="@color/background_material_dark"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:layout_marginTop="30sp"

             />`

Comment: Solucionado perdón.. era problema de código !!!! GRACIAS